# Text transforms on all of objects properties, is there a better way?

Tags: c#, reflection, string, templating

Currently I am doing this:

I have text that looks like:

```
Hello ${user.name}, this is ....
```

And I do this:

```
public string TransformUser(User user, string text)
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);

  sb.Replace("${user.name}", user.Name);

  ...
  ...

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Is there a better way, maybe using reflection somehow to loop through the classes public properties?

**Edit**

**Would it be possible to make this method Generic, so I can pass any object to it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through all properties using reflection and replacing the keys in the string would look roughly like this:

```
var args = new object[0];
foreach(var prop in typeof(User).GetProperties()) {
  if (prop.CanRead) {
    string val = prop.GetGetMethod().Invoke(user, args).ToString();
    sb.Replace("${user." + prop.Name +"}", val);
  }
}
```

It uses `CanRead` to check if the property has getter and then invokes the getter to read the value. A value is converted to string simply using `ToString` which will probably work for primitive types (depending on the required behavior). This is case sensitive, so you may want to use `ToLower` if the users write keys using lowercase (as in your example).

Comment: You can also use prop.GetValue(user, null) instead of prop.GetGetMethod().Invoke(...)

Comment: Would it be possible to wrap this into a method that takes ANY object?

Comment: @Fadrian: Thanks, that's a good suggestion! @Blankman: Yes, it can work with any object. Either wrap it into a generic method and use `typeof(T)` (if the object type is known at compile-time), or use `user.GetType()` to get the current type of argument of type `object` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a `StringTemplate` class which could probably be modified to suit your needs... It behaves like `String.Format`, with a major difference : you can use names for placeholders, rather than indexes. The values to format can be specified as either a `IDictionary<string, object>`, or any object (in that case each placeholder will be replaced with the value of the property with the same name).

For instance :

```
// with a dictionary :
var values = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Title", "Mr." },
    { "LastName", "Smith" }
};
string a = StringTemplate.Format("Hello {Title} {LastName}", values);

// with an anonymous type :
string b = StringTemplate.Format(
    "Hello {Title} {LastName}",
     new { Title = "Mr.", LastName = "Smith" });
```

If you need to use the same template several times, you can create an instance of `StringTemplate` and reuse it for better performance (the template string will be parsed only once).

You can also specify format modifiers, like in `String.Format`.

To fit your exact needs, this class will need a few adjustments, but it shouldn't be too hard...

---

Here's the code :

```
public class StringTemplate
{
    private string _template;
    private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"(?<open>{+)(?<key>\w+)(?<format>:[^}]+)?(?<close>}+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public StringTemplate(string template)
    {
        template.CheckArgumentNull("template");
        this._template = template;
        ParseTemplate();
    }

    private string _templateWithIndexes;
    private List<string> _placeholders;

    private void ParseTemplate()
    {
        _placeholders = new List<string>();
        MatchEvaluator evaluator = (m) =>
        {
            if (m.Success)
            {
                string open = m.Groups["open"].Value;
                string close = m.Groups["close"].Value;
                string key = m.Groups["key"].Value;
                string format = m.Groups["format"].Value;

                if (open.Length % 2 == 0)
                    return m.Value;

                open = RemoveLastChar(open);
                close = RemoveLastChar(close);

                if (!_placeholders.Contains(key))
                {
                    _placeholders.Add(key);
                }

                int index = _placeholders.IndexOf(key);
                return string.Format("{0}{{{1}{2}}}{3}", open, index, format, close);
            }
            return m.Value;
        };
        _templateWithIndexes = _regex.Replace(_template, evaluator);
    }

    private string RemoveLastChar(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length > 1)
            return str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }

    public static implicit operator StringTemplate(string s)
    {
        return new StringTemplate(s);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _template;
    }

    public string Format(IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        values.CheckArgumentNull("values");

        object[] array = new object[_placeholders.Count];
        for(int i = 0; i < _placeholders.Count; i++)
        {
            string key = _placeholders[i];
            object value;
            if (!values.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                value = string.Format("{{{0}}}", key);
            }
            array[i] = value;
        }
        return string.Format(_templateWithIndexes, array);
    }

    private IDictionary<string, object> MakeDictionary(object obj)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        foreach (string propName in _placeholders)
        {
            var prop = type.GetProperty(propName);
            if (prop != null)
                dict.Add(propName, prop.GetValue(obj, null));
        }
        return dict;
    }

    public string Format(object values)
    {
        return Format(MakeDictionary(values));
    }

    public static string Format(string template, IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        return new StringTemplate(template).Format(values);
    }

    public static string Format(string template, object values)
    {
        return new StringTemplate(template).Format(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the properties by calling `typeof(User).GetProperties()`.